# Mongodb aggregate to add field using map, filter, reduce

Tags: mongodb

Update: I think i was not clear in my description (very sorry) so I made an update to the question to be more clear for what I need

I have the following data in MongoDB

```
    {
    "category": "Threats",
    "_id": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
    "Relations" : [
            {
                "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
                "Breaches" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c04a")
            },
            {
                "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
                "Stories" : ObjectId("5e13a29453ff464eb389c79b")
            },
            {
                "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
                "Videos" : ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d3ef")
            },
            {
                "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
                "Actors" : ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d59f")
            },
            {
                "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
                "Companies" : ObjectId("5e13a2c953ff464eb389cfa0")
            },
            {
                "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
                "Stories" : ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d5b3")
            }
        ]
    }
```

and I want to know what is the most efficient way to add another field (finalArray) that includes all the ObjectId that is not Threats like so :

Update: I want the finalArray field to have all the ids that are not equal to the item id. I hope that makes sense, and I was clear enough,

```
{
"finalArray" : [
        ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c04a"),
        ObjectId("5e13a29453ff464eb389c79b"),
        ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
        ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d3ef"),
        ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d59f"),
        ObjectId("5e13a2c953ff464eb389cfa0"),
        ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d5b3")
    ]
}
```

I was trying to do it for a long time :(, and I did it but I have used a lot of pipe stages to make it and i feel it is not efficient at all, so I appreciate any help in this as there is a lot of tasks in my project that depends on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the finalArray field to have all the ids that are not equal to the item id"? What is `the item id`? Your expected result includes `ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385")` which is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the shortest aggregation but it works:

```
db.col.aggregate([
   {
      $facet:
         {
            Relations: [{ $match: {} }],
            finalArray: [
               { $unwind: "$Relations" },
               { $unset: "Relations.Threats" },
               { $set: { Relations: { $objectToArray: "$Relations" } } },
               { $unwind: "$Relations" },
               {
                  $group: {
                     _id: "$_id",
                     finalArray: { $push: "$Relations.v" },
                  }
               },
            ]
         }
   },
   { $unwind: "$Relations" },
   { $unwind: "$finalArray" },
   { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$Relations._id", "$finalArray._id"] } } },
   {
      $project: {
         _id: "$finalArray._id",
         Relations: "$Relations.Relations",
         finalArray: "$finalArray.finalArray",
      }
   }
])
```

Mongo [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ED8YzOFuuw)

```
 [
  {
    "Relations": [
      {
        "Breaches": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c04a"),
        "Threats": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385")
      },
      {
        "Stories": ObjectId("5e13a29453ff464eb389c79b"),
        "Threats": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385")
      },
      {
        "Threats": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"),
        "Videos": ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d3ef")
      },
      {
        "Actors": ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d59f"),
        "Threats": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385")
      },
      {
        "Companies": ObjectId("5e13a2c953ff464eb389cfa0"),
        "Threats": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385")
      },
      {
        "Stories": ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d5b3"),
        "Threats": ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385")
      }
    ],
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "finalArray": [
      ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c04a"),
      ObjectId("5e13a29453ff464eb389c79b"),
      ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d3ef"),
      ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d59f"),
      ObjectId("5e13a2c953ff464eb389cfa0"),
      ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d5b3")
    ]
  }
]
```

Another solution, which I like much more:

```
db.col.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { finalArray: "$Relations" } },
   { $unset: "finalArray.Threats" },
   { $set: { finalArray: { $mergeObjects: "$finalArray" } } },
   { $set: { finalArray: { $objectToArray: "$finalArray" } } },
   { $set: { finalArray: "$finalArray.v" } }
])
```

If you only need the `finalArray` then use:

```
db.col.aggregate([
   { $project: { finalArray: "$Relations" } },
   { $unset: "finalArray.Threats" },
   { $set: { finalArray: { $mergeObjects: "$finalArray" } } },
   { $set: { finalArray: { $objectToArray: "$finalArray" } } },
   { $set: { finalArray: "$finalArray.v" } }
])
```

Comment: Hello Wernfried, Thanks for your answer, I am studying it right now to see if it will solve my problem, Also I have updated my question to be more clear, what I really need is to grab all the relations ids that are not equal to the item id. Thanks in advance and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit, Thanks a lot for your Answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only fixed number of keys inside array and you know all of them.
then you can use this query.

```
  db.collection.aggregate([ {
        $addFields: {
          finalArray: { $concatArrays : [                 
              "$Relations.Breaches",
              "$Relations.Stories",
              "$Relations.Companies",
              "$Relations.Actors",
              "$Relations.Videos"]}
        }
      }])
```

The Result of the Above Query

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e3bd0a17f1e40317b8c4377"), 
"Relations" : [
    {
        "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"), 
        "Breaches" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c04a")
    }, 
    {
        "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"), 
        "Stories" : ObjectId("5e13a29453ff464eb389c79b")
    }, 
    {
        "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"), 
        "Videos" : ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d3ef")
    }, 
    {
        "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"), 
        "Actors" : ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d59f")
    }, 
    {
        "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"), 
        "Companies" : ObjectId("5e13a2c953ff464eb389cfa0")
    }, 
    {
        "Threats" : ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c385"), 
        "Stories" : ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d5b3")
    }
], 
"finalArray" : [
    ObjectId("5e13a29353ff464eb389c04a"), 
    ObjectId("5e13a29453ff464eb389c79b"), 
    ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d5b3"), 
    ObjectId("5e13a2c953ff464eb389cfa0"), 
    ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d59f"), 
    ObjectId("5e13a2ca53ff464eb389d3ef")
]
```

}

Comment: Hello Mohammad, Thanks for your answer, Sorry I was not clear in my description so I have updated the question, what I need is to grab all relations ids that are not equal to the item id, Thanks in advance and I appreciate your help.